# Как правильно перегрузить оператор <=> с++20

Tags: c++, перегрузка-операторов, c++20

Я пытаюсь перегрузить оператора <=>, но следующий код выдает ошибку компиляции

> error: no match for ‘operator==’ (operand types are ‘example’ and
> ‘example’)

```
struct example {
    int a{0};
    int b{0};
    auto operator <=>(const example& other) const{
        return a<=>other.a;
    }
};

int main() {
    example a{1, 2};
    example b{1, 3};
    a == b;
    return 0;
}
```

при это если я напишу auto `operator <=>(const example& other) const = default;`
ошибки компиляции не будет. Но я не могу писать default, так как мне нужна слегка измененная логика. Операторы <> работают.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Если вы определяете "ракету" **не** по умолчанию, то операторы `==` (и, не обязательно, `!=`) вы должны определить самостоятельно.

*Пользовательский* оператор `<=>` отключает генерацию равенства.

Ну, как если вы определяете пользовательский конструктор — всё, компилятор генерировать конструктор по умолчанию не станет. Так и здесь.

Так что определите свой оператор

```
auto operator ==(const example& other) const{
    return a==other.a;
}
```

и все заработает. Вот если есть оператор `==`, и нет оператора `!=`, то этот оператор неравенства будет сгенерирован из оператора равенства, как отрицание его результата.